# Why are Maven generated-sources not getting compiled?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a plugin which generates sources under the `target/generated-sources/wrappers` directory. It's wired into the generate-sources phase like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>xml2java</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is, when I use `mvn deploy` the `.class` files won't be placed in the jar. I see all the `.java` files there, but no `.class`.

I read all the issues around this problem, but couldn't figure out how to solve the problem. I'm using Maven 3.0.x.

Comment: The answer of the linked question also mentions the same `build-helper-maven-plugin`. And virtually everything that worked Maven 2 also works in Maven 3. This is why all this [`maven-X` tagging is nonsense](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147095/191131).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The build-helper plugin indeed solved the problem. Thanks @Joe for the comment.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wrappers</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 24):

If you have written the plugin by yourself you can programatically add the path with the generated sources to the maven source paths.

```java
@Mojo(name = "generate")
public class MyCodegenMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
    private MavenProject project;

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException{
        // your generator code

        project.addCompileSourceRoot("path/to/your/generated/sources");
    }

}
```

For example the raml-jaxrs-codegen plugin uses this technique. See [RamlJaxrsCodegenMojo.java](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-jaxrs-codegen/blob/master/maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/raml/jaxrs/codegen/maven/RamlJaxrsCodegenMojo.java) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such important note! It saved me a lot of time!