# Is it possible to configure maven to compile generated sources wouthout the use of a plugin?

Tags: java, maven, code-generation

I know this question is not new. But it seems that there is no definite answer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4121130/1303323) from 2012 states that if generated sources are placed under `target/generated-sources/<tool>` they will be compiled. [ANTLR 4 maven plugin](https://www.antlr.org/api/maven-plugin/latest/antlr4-mojo.html) follows this paradigm. Per documentation, the default value of outputDirectory is: `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/antlr4`.

Now in my case I have a custom tool that generates sources. I've set its output directory to be at `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/whatever` and it didn't work. Regarding the `whatever`part, I've tried to use the id of the goal that generates the sources and even tried to hijack `antlr4` name. No result though.

When I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682602/1303323) that suggests using mojo `build-helper-maven-plugin` it compiles as expected. But according to [maven guide to generating sources](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-generating-sources.html) it should be working without any helper plugin, shouldn't it? Am I missing something?

---

Here is the POM (fragment) configuration that I use to generate the sources.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-code</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
        <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
        <executableDependency>
            <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
            <artifactId>CodeGenerator</artifactId>
        </executableDependency>
        <arguments>
            <argument>${basedir}/</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/generate-code/</argument>
        </arguments>
        <mainClass>com.company.codegeneration.CodeGenerator</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
            <artifactId>CodeGenerator</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Your plugin should add the source to the project It means your plugin should do it correctly like https://github.com/mojohaus/templating-maven-plugin

Comment: BTW. do not use back-slashes within a pom file ...furthermore you should really create a correct plugin which can be bound to the life cycle like `generate-source` and handle that correctly.

Comment: @khmarbaise to be honest, I didn't know what to do with the (back)slashes. Thanks for pointing it out. If your suggestion is creating a plugin please by all means post it as answer. I know there is already one, but as I already pointed to the poster, it's not stating explicitly "make a plugin or it won't work".

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is just a bit incorrect.

> Nothing automatic, **plugins generating source code typically handle that by adding their output directory** (something like target/generated-sources/ by convention) as source directory to the POM so that it will be included later during the compile phase.
>
> Some less well implemented plugins don't do that for you and you have
>   to add the directory yourself, for example using the Build Helper
>   Maven Plugin.

As the other answer noted, most plugins typically add the generated code as new source path.

Ex: See [antlr4's Antlr4Mojo.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/antlr4-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/antlr/mojo/antlr4/Antlr4Mojo.java) class. Here, the plugin is adding the generated classes to project source by calling `addSourceRoot` method in `execute` method.

```
    //  Omitted some code
  void addSourceRoot(File outputDir) {
            if (generateTestSources) {
                project.addTestCompileSourceRoot(outputDir.getPath());
            }
            else {
                project.addCompileSourceRoot(outputDir.getPath());
            }
          }


    //  Omitted some code

 @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    //  Omitted code
        if(project!=null)

        {
            // Tell Maven that there are some new source files underneath the output
            // directory.
            addSourceRoot(this.getOutputDirectory());
        }
}
    //  Omitted some code
```

So, you can either do this in your custom plugin or use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Hello Ramu and thanks for taking the time to answer. Though your answer raises more questions than it solves: do I need to create a plugin to make that work? Is there a way to have the same result as `project.addCompileSourceRoot(...);` call but manually added on the pom? I am trying to _understand_ not just have a _solution_ :)

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis Sorry for the confusion. When you said _I have custom tool_, I thought you were using a plugin that you have created and told you to add that code in your plugin code. If that is not the case, then you can use `build-helper-maven-plugin` which does the same thing. (i.e. Attaching the additional source roots by taking the source path(s) as parameter and then executes the `project.addCompileSourceRoot(...)` to attach all the paths passed to the plugin as `<sources>`. There is no other way to add the path directly on the pom.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis In short, you don't need to create your own plugin just to add the newly generated path as source root. You can do that using `build-helper-maven-plugin`. If you are using a plugin that is developed by you, then you can add `project.addCompileSourceRoot(...)` to that plugin's execute method. You **can't** add the path without a plugin's help.